# Adding to build variant source set inside afterEvaluate

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to create a gradle plugin that generates source code for specific variants. The output directory of these generation tasks needs to be added to the appropriate variant's source set.

Currently I'm doing this inside an `afterEvaluate` block (included in the app's `build.gradle` for simplicity):

```
android {
  ...
  productFlavors {
    foo {}
    bar {}
  }
}

afterEvaluate {
  android.sourceSets.each { sourceSet ->
    sourceSet.java.srcDirs += new File(project.buildDir, "generated/source/mygeneratedsource/${sourceSet.name}")
  }
}
```

And my directory structure ends up like this (using default package for brevity):

```
app
 \--build
     \--generated
         \--source
             \--mygeneratedsource
                 \--foo
                     \--GeneratedClass.java
                 \--bar
                     \--GeneratedClass.java
 \--src
     \--main
         \--java
             \--MyApp.java
```

It seems that Android Studio is picking up the new directories as valid variant-specific source directories (I can reference GeneratedClass from inside MyApp) but if I try to compile I get:

```
error: cannot find symbol GeneratedClass
```

Does anyone know why AS can resolve the symbol but during compilation it fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that the sources are set on the compiler during evaluation so mutating the sourceSets after evaluation does not affect compilation.
Fortunately, for generated sources, the Android build system provides a couple of convenience methods, [registerJavaGeneratingTask](http://dcow.io/android-gradle-plugin-docs/com/android/build/gradle/api/BaseVariant.html#registerJavaGeneratingTask(org.gradle.api.Task%2C%20java.io.File)) and it's resource variant (registerResGeneratingTask). You can use these to register the generated class folders and the plugin will then include these on the compile path.

If these sources aren't being generated as a result of task, you can just create a dummy task, e.g. `project.task("register${variant.name.capitalize()}GeneratedSources")` and register that task as a java generating task with the appropriate sources and it should still work.